# Why does jOOQ map DSL.currentLocalDateTime() to current_timestamp instead of localtimestamp?

Tags: oracle, jooq

`org.jooq.impl.DSL.currentLocalDateTime()` is rendered in SQL dialect Oracle as `current_timestamp` (see class `org.jooq.impl.CurrentTimestamp`, relevant code not publicly available).

In Java 8 `java.time.LocalDateTime` is a date-time **without** a time-zone. Therefore I would expect jOOQ to render `LOCALTIMESTAMP` and not `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` because [the difference between `LOCALTIMESTAMP` function and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is that `LOCALTIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP` value while `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions079.htm).

How can I force jOOQ to render a timestamp without time zone? Preferably without defining a `CustomField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting observation indeed. This is historic, because the [`DSL.currentTimestamp()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#currentTimestamp--) method generates a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` expression but maps that to `java.sql.Timestamp` (which is an equivalent type to `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

The best workaround for you would be to use [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql), as always in these cases:

```
public static Field<LocalDateTime> localtimestamp() {
    return DSL.field("localtimestamp", LocalDateTime.class);
}
```